# Stop Intellij IDEA from saving modified files at exit

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I personally don't like any autosave behaviour in *Intellij IDEA*, so I have both ["**Save files on frame deactivation**"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/saving-and-reverting-changes.html?#d1542336e137) and ["**Save files automatically if application is idle for N seconds**"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/saving-and-reverting-changes.html?#d1542336e137) **off** and ["**Mark modified tabs with asterisk**"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/saving-and-reverting-changes.html?#d1542336e169) **on**.

Still, *IDEA* seems to have a nasty feature of silently saving **all** modified files whenever I exit the IDE.

1. How can I disable the above "autosave at exit", as it's very irritating?
2. How can I bulk reset all modified buffers to the (saved) on-disk state, without cycling through all project files, finding tabs with an asterisk, and undoing my changes? *Version Control* window is only a partial workaround since not all files in the project are controlled by VCS. *Local History* is not a solution, either, since (**A**) it only allows to revert one change at a time (no "bulk revert") and (**B**) it doesn't mark any moment in history which conforms to the current on-disk state.

Comment: I use IntelliJ, and I can play the devil's advocate by warning you that if IntelliJ were to exit on its own then autosave on exit might be the behavior you desire.  This might happen, for example, if a Windows Update takes place when you are not in front of your computer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. IntelliJ IDEA saves all modified files on many different occasions, not just on exit, but also before compilation, before running most external operations such as VCS operations, and so on. A lot of implementation code in IntelliJ IDEA relies on being able to do that, and therefore it's not possible for users to disable this behavior.

Note that "Local history" does allow you to perform bulk revert if you invoke it on a directory.